# Multi level population in Mongoose is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three models, programs (Program), tiers(Tier), offers (Offer). A program can have multiple tiers and a tiers can have multiple offers. So my program has an array of tiers and correspondingly a tier can have array of offers. Now I am trying to populate programs as follows:

```
var Program = mongoose.model('Program');
var Offer = mongoose.model('Offer');
var Tier = mongoose.model('Tier');

Program.findOne({
        _id: p_id
    }).populate('tiers').exec(function(err, docs){
        var opts = {
            path: 'tiers.offers'
        }
        Program.populate(docs, opts, function(err, docs){
            console.log('populated');
//          var s = require('util').inspect(docs, {depth : null})
            console.log(docs);
            console.log(docs.tiers[0]); //Printing complete tier information
            console.log(docs.tiers[0].offers[0]) //Just printing Object ID, not taking data from offers table
        })
    })
```

Problem is it is just populating tiers and not offers. How do I go deeper? Corresponding example is here:

https://github.com/paulcsmith/mongoose-currency/blob/master/node_modules/mongoose/examples/population-across-three-collections.js

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I have a song that haves mixes (Next songs) and also Artists. In here first I find the song by name, then I populate the songs that go next and also their Artists, on the song that goes next I populate the song and also the Artist information.

Hope it helps.

```
Song.find({songName: req.params.id})
  .lean()
  .populate({ path: 'songMixs songArtist' })
  .exec(function(err, docs) {

    var options = {
      path: 'songMixs.nextSong',
      model: 'Song'
    };

    if (err) return res.json(500);
    Song.populate(docs, options, function (err, projects) {

        var options2 = {
            path: 'songMixs.nextSong.songArtist',
            model: 'Artist'
        };

        Artist.populate(docs, options2, function (err, projects) {
            res.json(projects);
        });
        //res.json(projects);
    });
  });
```

Comment: This line, `.populate({ path: 'songMixs songArtist' })` really helped me understand how to populate 2 paths at once...thank you so greatly!